What is the earliest reliable source that prohibits teaching Torah and/or Mishna to gentiles after Moses translated the Torah into 70 languages?
I have read numerous conflicting opinions regarding this subject.  I am seeking the first "original" or earliest reliable source that prohibited teaching the Torah and/or Mishna to the nations which appears to be a contradiction to Moshe's example through translation of the text (I am not addressing or contradicting any psakim here who may explain how Moshe Rabbeinu did or did not translate and/or what was or was not included in that).  I'm soley trying to find a source for the original prohibition.

It is a gemara in Sanhedrin although I do not remember which daf.

59a in Sanhedrin
